# How to get proper error message running Web Tests on build server

Tags: .net, teamcity, mstest, web-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm running Visual Studio Web Performance Tests ([*.webtest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182539.aspx)) on the build server (TeamCity 8):

> mstest /TestContainer:ControllerWebTest.webtest

and in case of error getting a meaningless error message:

> 1 primary requests, 0 dependant requests and 0 conditional rules failed

How to configure TC/MSBuild/MSTest to output proper error message?

Comment: I had similar problem running web tests combined in an ordered test with VS2010 (see [MS statement](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/44c6ca51-0773-4bfa-8c4e-519b1ee48a2f/web-test-details-are-not-displayed-when-ran-from-an-ordered-test?forum=vstswebtest)). It looks like you are running in  the same problem running your tests using TestContainer. BTW, my problem was solved with VS2012. Which VS version are you using?

Comment: @Elena: Thanks for the link. Looks like the only way to check the results is to open output files manually.

Comment: @Elena: I run mstest.exe from VS 2013 Ultimate installation folder.

Comment: @Elena: How do you run your tests? What was the output in VS 2010 and what was changed in VS 2012? Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem running ordered test from _VS2010_ and running it  via _tcm.exe_ as a part of automated tests (I had a _Test Case_ automated by this ordered test). I only could see which _Web Tests_ were successfully and which failed but I could not see why since I could not see any details (request, responce etc.). See screenshot I loaded up when asking the question on MS Developer Network forum. Using _VS2012_ I could see all these details perfectly. (Unfortunately, I haven't try it with _VS2013_ yet.)

Comment: Just realized that you don't really have the same problem I had... you "just" can't see the error message in your build log, right? If you open *.trx file in VS you can see all the details (error messages). Seems I misunderstood you question, sorry for that!